# disallowed_user_agent on Google sign in if user tries to login from Facebook webview

Tags: node.js, passport-google-oauth

So I have a nodejs app that allows Logging in with Google and Facebook. While Facebook works just fine, it doesn't want to work with Google signing in, I get the disallowed_user_agent error. I tried to force it into the native browser by using the following code:

```
 document.getElementById("google-login-btn").addEventListener("click", function (event) {
     event.preventDefault();
     const isFacebookApp = /FBAN|FBAV/.test(navigator.userAgent);
     //If Facebook App, open up a new window.
    if (isFacebookApp) {
     window.open("https://example.com/auth/google", "_blank");
    } else {
     window.location.href = "https://example.com/auth/google";
    }
    });
```

It's a nodejs web application. I have been sharing this app with my friends over Facebook and it's a pain to tell them to copy/paste the link into their browser.